# Is it possible "def" value in build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am generating multiple `apk's` based on different config files.

So i defined a variable on `build.gradle` file

```
def isPRODBuild = false
```

I want to change this variable in `productFlavors` scope, so i did following.

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        isPRODBuild= false     
    }
    prod {
        isPRODBuild= true 
    }
}
```

But it seems like that its not changing the value of `isPRODBuild` value.

Do in need to use some other type of variable in build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

> At build time, Gradle generates the BuildConfig class so your app code
>   can inspect information about the current build. You can also add
>   custom fields to the BuildConfig class from your Gradle build
>   configuration file using the buildConfigField() method and access
>   those values in your app's runtime code. Likewise, you can add app
>   resource values with resValue().

So you could simply use [buildConfigField](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code) to define your variable.

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "isPRODBuild", "false"   
    }
    prod {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "isPRODBuild", "true"
    }
}
```

Then to access the aforementioned variable simply use `BuildConfig.isPRODBuild`